# How and when BinderProxy Created?

Tags: java, android, android-binder

We all know that stub and proxy transact parcel by member 'mRemote'. but what is 'mRemote'?
BinderProxy? How and when BinderProxy Created?

```
private static class Proxy implements com.aispeech.ccui.launcher.IElevatorService
    {
      private android.os.IBinder mRemote;
      Proxy(android.os.IBinder remote)
      {
        mRemote = remote;
      }
      @Override public android.os.IBinder asBinder()
      {
        return mRemote;
      }
      public java.lang.String getInterfaceDescriptor()
      {
        return DESCRIPTOR;
      }
      @Override public void actionUp() throws android.os.RemoteException
      {
          boolean _status = mRemote.transact(Stub.TRANSACTION_actionUp, _data, _reply, 0);
       
      }
    }
```